# Covert Sql Code into Laravel query structure.The current one not working on DB::raw,select etc

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to run the code in laravel.By applying below methods it does not work.Please any body can add the sql code into laravel structure.
DB::raw();
DB::select does not work there.

```
 SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
    'max(case when field_key = ''',
    field_key,
    ''' then field_value end) ',
    field_key
    )
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM
    data_translation WHERE `table_name`='categories';
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT categories.*,`refrence_id`, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM data_translation
    JOIN categories on categories.id=data_translation.refrence_id
    GROUP BY refrence_id');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below statement

```
\DB::statement(<-- Your Query -->);
```

Comment: There are multiple query in the sql.the statement command does not give result.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this in your function

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from your_table"));
```

then you can check your data like this

```
dd($data);
```

and dont forget to add `use DB;`

or you can try to transform your query to stored procedure and then you can call your stored procedure like this

```
$data = DB::select('exec sp_yourStoredProcedureName');
```